# WhatsApp not detecting WhatsApp folder

Tags: whatsapp, photos

bought lumia 640xl and lumia 730, repenting now. whatsapp is not detecting its own folder. not only that, infact whatsapp folder is not able to see in photos gallery as well. i am confused now whether whatsapp problem or windows problem.

Comment: Is this a folder on the phone, or on an SD card?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Goto the Location of the Whatsapp folder which is not been detected by your photos app and Whatsapp
2. Rename the folder to Whatsapp1 or whatspp2 or anything u like
3. Move to whatsapp and download some pic or video which was sent in whatsapp
4. now mobile has created a new folder "whatsapp". This will be detected by the photos app and whatsapp too
   You can then move the contents from whatsapp1 folder to your new whatsapp folder

This worked for me

Comment: I also have done the Solution for Whatsapp folder in Lumia device
first, rename the folder again change the folder name same when you renamed
and start the Whatsapp apps inthe phone.
That's has done and worked.